# Freeing malloc'ed memory from circular linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I apologize in advance if this is an incredibly dumb question...

Currently I have a circular linked list. The number of nodes is normally held static. When I want to add to it, I malloc a number of nodes (ex. 100000 or so) and splice it in. This part works fine when I malloc the nodes one by one.

I want to attempt to allocate by blocks:

```
NODE *temp_node = node->next;
NODE *free_nodes = malloc( size_block * sizeof( NODE ) );
node->next = free_nodes;
for ( i = 0; i < size_block - 1; i++ ) {
    free_nodes[i].src = 1;
    free_nodes[i].dst = 0;
    free_nodes[i].next = &free_nodes[i+1];
}
free_nodes[size_block - 1].next = temp_node;
```

The list works as long as I don't attempt to free anything ('glibc detected: double free or corruption' error). Intuitively, I think that is because freeing it doesn't free the single node, and looping through the normal way is attempting to free it multiple times (plus freeing the entire block probably screws up all the other pointers from the nodes that still exist?), but:

1. Could somebody please explain to me explicitly what is happening?
2. Is there a way to allocate the nodes by blocks and not break things?

The purpose of this is because I am calling malloc hundreds of thousands of times, and it would be nice if things were faster. If there is a better way around this, or I can't expect it to get faster, I would appreciate hearing that too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the way you allocated your nodes in blocks, you always have to `free` the whole block with exactly the same start address as you got from `malloc`. There is no way around this, `malloc` is designed like this.

Putting up your own ways around this is complicated and usually not worth it. Modern run-times have quite efficient garbage collection behind `malloc`/`free` (for its buffers, not for user allocations) and it will be hard for you to achieve something better, better meaning more efficient but still guaranteeing the consistency of your data.

Before losing yourself in such a project measure where the real bottlenecks of your program are. If the allocation part is a problem there is still another possibility that is more likely to be the cause, namely bad design. If you are using so many elements in your linked list such that allocation dominates, probably a linked list is just not the appropriate data structure. Think of using an array with a moving cursor or something like that.

Comment: Accepting, because I ended up re-arranging how things worked and went back to a circular buffer after sitting down and reflecting on what was important. Thanks to everybody that answered! :)

Comment: @user962158, thanks. For the downvoters, if they happen to pass here again, would you mind to explain?

Comment: @JensGustedt - This is a total necro, but I believe I know why you got downvoted: C doesn't have garbage collection.

Comment: @Polynomial, argh, I never said that C has garbage collection. I said that the implementations of malloc/free have it for themselves behind the scenes.

Comment: @JensGustedt - That's probably the misunderstanding that got you downvoted. Though malloc and free just tend to call the underlying OS calls for memory management (e.g. VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree), so it's pretty much a moot point.

Answer (score 3):

> Could somebody please explain to me explicitly what is happening?

Exactly what you said. You are allocating a single space of contiguous memory for all blocks. Then if you free it, all memory will be released.

> Is there a way to allocate the nodes by blocks and not break things?

Allocate different memory segments for each block. In your code (that isn't complete) should be something like:

```
for ( i = 0; i < size_block ; i++ ) {
    free_nodes[i] = malloc (sizeof( NODE ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you free a node you free the entire allocation that the node was allocated with.  You must somehow arrange to free the entire group of nodes at once.

Probably your best bet is to keep a list of "free" nodes and reuse those rather than allocating/freeing each node.  And with some effort you can arrange to keep the nodes in blocks and allocate from the "most used" block first such that if an entire block goes empty you can free it.